# TabBar Controller item animation use in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have been developing ios using swift for 3 months.I am just little bit curious about interesting animations.I have been using application and this application has interesting tab bar item .This bar item changed itself every 3 seconds .How can ı code that?? [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duzqg.png) [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj7LU.jpg) [Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMt5P.png). Thank for eveything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpler way to doing this. Add the following code in the tabbar delegate:

```
class MySubclassedTabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  delegate = self
}
}

extension MySubclassedTabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate  {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    guard let fromView = selectedViewController?.view, let toView = viewController.view else {
      return false // Make sure you want this as false
    }

    if fromView != toView {
      UIView.transition(from: fromView, to: toView, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], completion: nil)
    }

    return true
}
}
```